# How to random every number we assign into a 2D Arrays in java?

Tags: java

I am trying to assign numbers randomly. I understand that `Math.random()` only goes between 0 and 1, and tried to multiply it by 10, and it still does not show any random numbers:

```
 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0
```

the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] mdArray = new int[5][5];

    for(int i = 0; i<mdArray.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<mdArray[i].length; j++) {
            mdArray[i][j] = (int)Math.random()*10;
            System.out.print(mdArray[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because your cast is wrong. The cast applies only to `Math.random()` with is less than 1, so it is always casted to 0 and `0*x = 0`.

Instead of `(int)Math.random()*10` you have to write `(int) (Math.random() * 10)`.

Comment: OMG, i had hunch it was the braces, but i didnt try it, thank you!!